# How can I deploy an exe file within my C++ code?

Tags: c++

I'm making a small prank in C++ that moves the cursor in random locations across the screen in a `while` loop. I want that loop to be in its own executable file. So I have a console application, and when it runs it asks for the screen resolution, then executes its logic. But if you just hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> it quits the program, so I want it to where when I launch the program it will ask the resolution, then deploy the prank executable in the current directory and run it, so that when I close my application, the prank is still running.

Comment: By "deploy" you mean "run"? And what platform?

Comment: deploy a different exe from my exe that has main(). if by platform you mean OS it's windows 7 64 bit

Comment: This is likely illegal.

Comment: No. It is not "Illegal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want it to where when I launch the program it will ask the resolution, then deploy the prank executable in the current directory and run it, so that when I close my application, the prank is still running.

Compile the prank EXE first, then use an `.RC` file to compile and link the prank EXE into a binary resource of your main EXE.  When the main EXE is run, it can extract the prank EXE to a file and then run it.  There is no standard API in C/C++ for accessing resources, you will have to use platform-specific APIs, like the `FindResource()`, `LoadResource()`, and `LockResource()` functions on Windows.

Or, your main EXE could simply contain the prank code directly, and then run a separate copy of itself with a different command line to execute the prank code.  You don't actually need a separate EXE for the prank (unless you really want one).